# awk range regex not beginning

Tags: regex, awk, regex-negation

I have some data like this

```
Data                    Table ABC
Data
Stop
Data
Data                    Stop
Data                    Foo
Data                    Foo
```

I am trying to setup an awk range for Table ABC until Stop in the same column.
I have tried this so far

```
awk '/Table ABC/,/Stop/' q
Data                    Table ABC
Data
Stop
```

But I desire to get

```
Data                    Table ABC
Data
Stop
Data
Data                    Stop
```

Comment: range patterns are very convenient but not extensible and you may paint yourself to a corner when extra features are needed.

Comment: No forgiveness necessary but have you tried solving your problem without a range expression? That **IS** the right approach so if you try it as you've been shown I think you may not actually have a question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the data file is not tabulated but in fixed length formatted, perhaps an alternative solution will work better

```
awk '{m=match($0,"Table ABC"); if(m>0) p=m} 
   p {print; if(p==match($0,"Stop")) exit}' file

Data                    Table ABC
Data
Stop
Data
Data                    Stop
```

mark the position of the match, start printing and end when the position matches the end pattern.

Regardless of the location of the match, if you want to end at the second occurrence of the end pattern:

```
awk '/Table ABC/{p=1} p; /Stop/ && ++c==2{exit}' file
```

counter `c` counts the end patterns and exits at the second time.

Comment: Yeah. I am doing something similar. awk '/Table ABC/{f=1} f{print} / Stop/{f=0}' I put a space in / Stop/.

Comment: that's the equivalent of the range pattern, just need to add counter.  Note also if you have only one instance to match (or the first) you can replace `f=0` with `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** *range pattern* solution:

```
awk -F"[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" '$2=="Table ABC", $2=="Stop"' file
```

The output:

```
Data                    Table ABC
Data
Stop
Data
Data                    Stop
```

---

> A *range pattern* is made of two patterns separated by a comma, in the
>   form ‘`begpat, endpat`’. It is used to match ranges of consecutive
>   input records. The first pattern, `begpat`, controls where the range
>   begins, while `endpat` controls where the pattern ends.

Comment: if its a pattern, is it possible to do a negate? Such as, don't do first match? I am not good with regex thats why i ask. (?^Stop)?

Comment: @NinjaGaiden, **When a record matches begpat, the range pattern is turned on, and the range pattern matches this record as well. As long as the range pattern stays turned on, it automatically matches every input record read. The range pattern also matches endpat against every input record; when this succeeds, the range pattern is turned off again for the following record.**

Comment: @NinjaGaiden, yes, we can use "negation" pattern but it'll impact the whole range

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` in this context as it's ambiguous. Use the word `string`, or `regexp`, or `condition` or `expression` - whichever it is you mean. In the above conversation `pattern` is being used to mean multiple different things which just muddies the waters. I know some awk documentation talks about patterns - that is a confusion-generator!